# SSH Server not allowing Tunneling

Tags: ssh

I'm writing to figure out why an SSH server on a rig isn't allowing tunneling. This is the sshd_config, looked perfectly fine to me.

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd(8) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

UsePAM yes

PermitTunnel yes
PermitOpen localhost:324
GatewayPorts yes
AllowTcpForwarding yes
```

When running **sudo netstat -lptu**, my port doesn't come up as listening. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you verified that the key files actually exist?

Comment: authorized_keys? Yes they're there.

Comment: How are you trying to set up the tunnel

Comment: I'm using Putty, Dynamic and Auto for port 324 and tried 9998.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I jumped to the wrong conclusion in my other answer.

Here's a question addressing what the PuTTY Local, Remote, and Dynamic options are:

https://serverfault.com/questions/272754/what-is-the-difference-between-local-remote-dynamic-ssh-tunneling

Dynamic means opening a local port and acting as a SOCKS proxy for various connections out through whatever ports on the remote host.

If you want to open a port on the remote host to forward things back through the client, you'll need to use the Remote option with an appropriate destination.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to open a port <1024 as a non-root user.  If you log in to your SSH session as root, I'd expect it to work.

Comment: I've tried ports higher and lower than 1024, and I'm in as root all the time. Still no luck.

Comment: If you're in as root, why do you have to sudo your netstat?